# Distinct query in has_many relationship with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Having troubles figuring out the most efficient way to handle this kind of query.

I have 3 models:

`User`, `Location` and `Query`

```rb
# User
has_many :queries

# Query
belongs_to: :user
belongs_to :location
```

I use `user.queries` for stats as it contains extra metadata, there's a lot of duplicates on the `location_id` column if they happen to perform the same query, but each would have different metadata so it's recorded as a separate record.

I would like to build a so called `history` that selects the most recent distinct `location_id` from `User.queries` and returns them by order of either `id` or `created_at` while still keeping it as an ActiveRecord Collection and not converting it to an array so that it can be iterated through for rendering.

`user.queries.select(:location_id).distinct` is close but it's not ordered.

The following raw SQL appears to be working but is there a way to write it with ActiveRecord

```rb
queries.find_by_sql("
      SELECT location_id, created_at
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (queries.location_id) *
        FROM queries
        ORDER BY queries.location_id, queries.created_at DESC) queries
      ORDER BY queries.created_at DESC
      LIMIT 20
    ")
```

Answer (score 0):

[`uniq`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/uniq) would be as close as you can get

```
user.queries.order('queries.created_at DESC').pluck(:location_id).uniq
user.queries.select("location_id, queries.created_at").map(&:location_id).uniq
```